# Can i get return value from confirm on beforeunload

Tags: javascript

When I return string I can pop up confirm before refreshing the page.

```js
  window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      new Promise((res, rej) => {
        return res();
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("I want to see my it when blue button is clicked")
      })
    }, 1);
    return "";
  };
```

I've tried to get return value from confirm whether user clicked ok or cancle, but failed. Is it possible?

Comment: just so that i got u.. when the confirm shows up.. u want to see *THAT CONFIRM'S RETURN VALUE*? as in if you click `OK` it returns `true` and stuff?

Comment: I would say to hijack the function(except changing the name `confirm` into some other thing doesn't work)

Comment: the solution would be able to do this(take a function as an argument and change its real value as though it was passed as a reference).. changing the constructor doesn't work.. if by some chance I could edit a function as an argument.. yea that will be possible :{

Answer (score 0):

the `beforeunload` event doesn't have a callback. You can use a timer to do the job though.

```
var timeout;

function warning() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('You stayed');
    }, 1000);
    return "You are leaving the page";
}

function noTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

window.onbeforeunload = warning;
window.unload = noTimeout;​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aPwfz/1/

Comment: Thank you for reply, I updated my question.